# asynchronous loading controller's code

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-routing

how do you bootstrap a controller that loaded asynchronously via require.js?
if I have something like that:

```
$routeProvider.when('/',
  {
    templateUrl:'view1.html',
    controller:'ctrl',
    resolve:{
      load:function($q){
        var dfrd = $q.defer();
        require(['view1-script'],function(){
          dfrd.resolve();
        })
        return dfrd.promise;
      }
    }
 })
```

why angular still won't find the controller? I am resolving the route after it loads the script

[check out this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YNbvYUhY6yeuI3UAA2Uq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try calling `$controllerProvider.register` to create your controller. I would also call `$apply()` on the `$rootScope` after resolving the deferred because without it, the view does not seem to appear:

```
load: function($q, $rootScope){
  var dfrd = $q.defer();
  require(['view1'],function(){
    dfrd.resolve();
    $rootScope.$apply();
  })
  return dfrd.promise;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/fe2Q3BhxPYnPmeiOORHP

in addition, here is a good post: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/05/22/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs.aspx

Answer (score -1):

It's been 3 years, but just in case anyone still interested, a few months ago I wrote [a post about a similar technique](http://www.developerdepueblo.com/angular/js/asynchronous-load-of-angularjs-controllers/) to do it.

The most important part is that second parameter of the method `$routeProvider.when(route, ctrl)` method can handle promises, so you can simply emulate it:

```
function controllerFactory(ctrl) {
  return {
    then: function (done) {
      var self = this;

      require(['./controller/' + ctrl], function (ctrl) {
        self.controller  = ctrl;
        self.resolve     = ctrl.resolve;
        self.templateUrl = ctrl.templateUrl;

         done();
      });
    }
  };
}
```

And you can end up writing your route definition like this:

```
$routeProvider.
  when('/some/route', controllerFactory('some/route')).
  when('/other/route', controllerFactory('other/route'))
```